# Database deployment for JSP and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jsp

I'm designing my first JSP application that will use hibernate to manage a quite simple database (a few tables with a few foreign keys).
By studying some tutorial about hibernate, I learnt that one of the great features of hibernate is that it is automatically creating db tables when first accessing them.
So what is the common best practice for deploying my jsp application on production machine:

1) Just don't care about db / tables creation and let hibernate to do the job "On the fly"

2) Use a ServletContextListener to check / install the DB at first run

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would suggest you to use JSF instead of JSP. JSP is a pretty old Java technology and unless your user interface/experience is very basic it will take a lot of effort to make it user friendly. Latest tutorials and official documentation for Java EE don't talk very much about JSP anymore because most of its functions are now incorporated into JSF.

At first look JSF may seem complex and difficult but I can assure you that in a very short time you will be creating great looking Web apps.

For database access I strongly suggest you to use JPA with Hibernate as the persistence provider. JPA is the standard way to connect to relational or even NoSQL databases.

More specifically about your question, JPA is configured in just one file (persistence.xml). You have three options for database/table creation which are defined by the JPA property *javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action*. Possible values are *create* and *drop-and-create*. The first value creates tables as needed and the second drops and recreates the tables when the entity manager factory is created. If the property is not present tables must be created manually.

In a production environment I don't like tables being automatically created so I don't use this feature. For test environments drop-and-create can be handy.

From the 2 options you suggested I would prefer number 2, but I don't like it. I would rather create the database and tables manually.

An example persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="ExamplePU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/example</non-jta-data-source>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```